# Elm Parser cannot Return String Inside Curly Braces

Tags: parsing, elm

I am new to the Elm parser library and I am trying to make a move away from using regex. I need to parse a string and return a list of strings for each string inside double curly braces like so `{{return this}}`  I am using the `Parser.sequence` function and this is my code

```
block : Parser (List String) 
block = 
  Parser.sequence
    { start = "{{"
    , separator = ""
    , end = "}}"
    , spaces = spaces
    , item = getSource
    , trailing = Optional
    }
```

My question is, What should I do in the `item` field to return the string in between the curly braces. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about creating your own parser for a word?

```
word : Parser String
word =
  getChompedString <|
    succeed ()
      |. chompIf Char.isAlphaNum
      |. chompWhile Char.isAlphaNum
```

It actually chomps alphanum characters, so `{{return textABC123}}` will result as `Ok ["return","textASD234"]`. For `{{return text}}` `Char.isLower` is sufficient.

Then you can use it in `sequence` instead of `getSource` (since `getSource` also chomps `}` characters, which is not suitable in the current situation):

```
block : Parser (List String) 
block = 
  Parser.sequence
    { start = "{{"
    , separator = ""
    , end = "}}"
    , spaces = spaces
    , item = word
    , trailing = Optional
    }
```

Here is [an ellie-app example](https://ellie-app.com/3fPCYv9mrjya1), which demonstrates it.

Answer (score 0):

You need a function returning a `Parser String`.
You could use the [variable](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/parser/latest/Parser#variable) function:

```
block : Parser (List String)
block =
    Parser.sequence
        { start = "{{"
        , separator = ""
        , end = "}}"
        , spaces = spaces
        , item =
            Parser.variable
                { start = Char.isAlphaNum
                , inner = Char.isAlphaNum
                , reserved = Set.empty
                }
        , trailing = Optional
        }
```

Example:

```
> Parser.run block "{{foo bar baz}}"
Ok ["foo","bar","baz"]
    : Result (List Parser.DeadEnd) (List String)
```